# Unable to get session.getAttribute in RequestMethod.POST

Tags: java, httpsession, oltu

I have tow method and using Spring MVC, first is a method=RequestMethod.GET and there I set session.setAttribute("clientId", "abc").
Second method is a method=RequestMethod.POST where I do this:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
System.out.println("-----" + (String)session.getAttribute("clientId"));
```

But always get null.

**[Edit]**

The thing here is the post method is not called by ModalandView("postpage"), its called by Http callout by Apache oltu internally

Answer (score 0):

In Get method do

```
 Session session = request.getSession(true); 
  session.setAttribute("clientId", "abc");
```

In Post do

```
String s = request.getSession().getAttribute("clientId");
```

Comment: tried it but it didn't worked for me, the thing here is the post method is not called by ModalandView("postpage"), its called by Http callout by Apache oltu internally.